# Como sincronizar chaves auto incremento entre bancos de dados diferentes no Firedac?

Tags: delphi, sqlite, firebird, firedac

Eu estou pesquisando como funcionam os campos auto incremento no Firedac, usando Delphi xE7 e consegui montar um exemplo da documentação que sincroniza duas tabelas master-detalhes com a chave correta. A dúvida surgiu quando eu quis fazer um espelho do meu servidor Firebird em SQLite, pois vou distribuir uma aplicação que precisa não só trabalhar *off-line*, como também persistir os dados ao fechar o aplicativo.

Então em minha aplicação remota eu adicionarei registros em duas tabelas (`Pedidos`,`Itens`) no esquema master-detalhe, que precisam ter uma chave estrangeira em comum. Ao conectar no servidor no final do dia eu quero enviar 
os pedidos e os itens novos, sabendo que podem haver outros usuarios que tambem geraram chaves SQLite iguais as minhas. Usando Firedac, como atualizá-las com chaves inéditas, sem perder o vinculo master-detalhe?
Lembrando que o servidor é Firebird e localmente é SQLite...

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes:

---

Primeiro: Firedac é acesso a dados então o autoincremento é algo do banco de dados e não do firedac. No Firebird 3 está disponível a opção de auto incremento sem o uso da combinação sequence/trigger.

```
fieldid bigint generated by default as identity primary key
```

Para ao inserir você ter o valor da ID o firebird oferece o recurso do returning

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (...) values (...) RETURNING idpk;
```

---

Segundo: No sistema que mantenho de automação de venda a tabela de pedidos(SQLLite) de cada vendedor possui uma ID própria, ao enviar o pedido para o banco de dados principal é usado a combinação IdVendedor/IdPedido para identificar de forma inequívoca o pedido. Ou seja estes campos são atributos da pedido no lado Firebird da força.

---

Uma solução para sincronizar primary key em diferentes aplicações que operem de forma assíncrona, independente do motivo de trabalhar assim, é o uso de UUID, [Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)
O UUID é um tipo hexadecimal de 128bits, o Firebird o utiliza um tipo char de 16 bytes para este fim. 
O Firebird traz as funções [GEN_UUID()](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-gen_uuid.html) desde a versão 2.1, [UUID_TO_CHAR()](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-uuid_to_char.html) e [CHAR_TO_UUID()](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-char_to_uuid.html) desde a versão 2.5, necessárias para o uso do UUID em sua aplicação no lado Firebird.

Quando ao SQLite: Consulte as referencias abaixo
[Geração do UUID](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/uuid-generation-in-sqlite-td35137.html)
[Exemplo de DDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104662/is-there-uid-datatype-in-sqlite-if-yes-then-how-to-generate-value-for-that)

Comment: Caro  Edison. Muito obrigado pelo comentário. Infelizmente este não é o ponto. O Firedac possui tantos recursos inteligentes  com  chaves e transações que deve haver um método melhor para fazer isso sem mexer no Banco. Lembrando que é importante pro meu projeto centralizar as regras de negocio no delphi. Sabemos por exemplo que o Firedac gerencia a geração de chaves quando trabalha offline, com commit. E funciona mesmo  com as  tabelas master-detalhe. Agora, em relação a INSERT INTO tab1 values (...) RETURNING idpk, não sei como tirar proveito disso estando o servidor off-line. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Vai depender de como está estruturado o software, considerando que a sua parte remota, não terá integração on-line com o server, uma maneira de ter esta "chave inédita" é utilizando UUID. Referencia em [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154868/firedac-batchmove-from-memorytable)